# Angular 2 Observable subscribe not working

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am trying to subscribe to an observable on init of a component like so:

```
    this.ticketService.getTicketsAsync(filters).subscribe(
        tickets => this.ticketResponse = tickets,
        () => console.log('hi'))
```

Is there any reason why the first lambda expression works, but the second one never does?

EDIT:

Here is the code hat getTicketAsync is returning:

```
getTicketsAsync(ticketFilters : TicketSearch): Observable<TicketResponse> {

    let api_endpoint = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'WebReport/request_report'
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers : headers, withCredentials : true});
    return this.http.post(api_endpoint, ticketFilters, options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);





}
```

Comment: what is `getTicketsAsync`, is it returning `Observable`? Please explain *Is there any reason why the first lambda expression works, but the second one never does?*?

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar Yeah, it's returning an observable. I'll post that code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is `catch` when observable throw error.

```
subscription = source.subscribe(
  x => console.log('onNext: %s', x),
  e => console.log('onError: %s', e),
  () => console.log('onCompleted'));
```

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md

**Solution:**
1. Use `onNext` hook:

```
this.ticketService.getTicketsAsync(filters).subscribe(
    tickets => {
      this.ticketResponse = tickets;
      console.log('hi');
    },
    () => console.log('ERROR!'));
```

2. Use `onCompleted` hook:

```
this.ticketService.getTicketsAsync(filters).subscribe(
  tickets => this.ticketResponse = tickets,
  error => console.log('ERROR: ' +error),
  () => console.log('hi')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

big arrows represent functions which makes your code like this

```
this.ticketService.getTicketsAsync(filters)
.subscribe(
  function(tickets){
    this.ticketResponse = tickets,
    function(){
      console.log("hi")
    }
  }
)
```

you are passing two arguments (which are two callback functions).

Comment: But Observable returns 3 callbacks hooks: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md

Comment: but you dont have to pass 3 arguments all the time,